# Exporting datagrid into Excel document

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, interop, export-to-excel

I need to export a datgrid to an excel document, but i'm encountering an error when doing so.  Below is the code i'm using to export, it opens up the Excel document, and the headers are in place, but where the values in each cell should be i'm seeing System.Data.DataRowView in the excel cell. What i need to do is take the values from hat row and insert them into the Excel workbook.

Any help is appreciated, or tutorial links.

Peter

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = null;

object missing = Type.Missing;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = null;

try
{
    excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

    for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; Idx++)
    {
        // Puts Column Header into excel work sheet
        ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dataGrid1.Columns[Idx].Header;
    }

    for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dataGrid1.Items.Count; Idx++)
    {  
        ws.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dataGrid1.Columns.Count].Value =
        dataGrid1.Items[Idx].ToString();
    }

    excel.Visible = true;
    wb.
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Excel: " + ex.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, if anybody ever has the same problem.

To access the the values inside the row here's what you need to:

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; columnIndex++) 
{
    ws.Range["A2"].Offset[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value =
        (dataGrid1.Items[rowIndex] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[columnIndex].ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the loop `for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dataGrid1.Items.Count; Idx++)` you are iterating over the items, i.e. the rows of the DataGrid. Each such item or row apparently is a [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx), and hence ToString gives you "System.Data.DataRowView".

You would also have to iterate over each item in a row, i.e. the cell:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGrid1.Items.Count; rowIndex++) 
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; columnIndex++) 
    {
        ws.Range["A2"].Offset[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value =
            dataGrid1.Items[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that i haven't tested this and don't know anything about the Excel API, so i'm not really sure if the `ws.Range["A2"].Offset[rowIndex, columnIndex]` thing is correct.

Comment: Thanks, i'l give it a try anyway and test to see if it works :)